# Windows 10 .bat script for mapping a file share that contains a folder the same name as their A.D. username

Tags: windows, batch-file, fileshare

I have a network file share for each user:  `\\network_share\users\jdoe`
where "jdoe" is their active directory account username.

Is there an environment variable that would work for this?

I attempted:

```
net use H: \\network_share\users\%USERPROFILE%
```

But that didn't work.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am confused as to why you would need this.  Windows Server has been able to automatically map HOME drives since Windows NT.  Not sure why you would need to run a batch file to map their HOME drive.  You have something configured incorrectly on your Domain controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a double backslash in the beginning of the network path. Also USERPROFILE is a path, not a name. Here:

```
net use H: \\network_share\users\%USERNAME%
```

Use `set | find "jdoe"`  to search for a specific string in the environment variables, both names and values.